# C# Get items from List of List of double[]

Tags: c#, list

I have this list

```
List<List<double[]>>MyList = new List<List<double[]>>();
```

Each item in **MyList** is a List of N items and each item is array of double

To get first list in MyList

```
 List<double[]>List1items = new List<double[]>();
 List1items = MyList[0];
```

BUT,

How to get:

[1] one value in the **idx** index form the list?

for example, something like this: "this code is not working"

```
double doubleValue = MyList[1][2][1];
```

[2] one row in the idx index form the list?

for example:

```
double[] RowValues = MyList[1][2];
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: @Blorgbeard it is not working

Comment: The first list in MyList is at position 0, not position 1: `List<double[]> items = MyList[0];` Keep that in mind for the other examples, too. Might you just be looking for an item that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I have corrected it

Comment: @shdotcom did you correct it everywhere? I see your code still shows `double doubleValue = MyList[1][2][1];` Are you certain you have a list with 2 lists of double arrays, And that the second of those lists has three double arrays, and that the third double array has two doubles in it? It would be helpful if you posted some code that populated your lists/arrays, so we are all working with the same data.

Comment: @RufusL L, in [1] and [2], I have not mentioned first index, "one value" means any value in any index. "one row" means any row in any index. These was just examples. However, the code working now, there was an ordering mistake in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
List<List<double[]>>MyList = new List<List<double[]>>();

        double[] items1 = {1.231, 4.561, 7.891};
        double[] items2 = {1.232, 4.562, 7.892};
        double[] items3 = {1.233, 4.563, 7.893};
        double[] items4 = {1.234, 4.564, 7.894};
        double[] items5 = {1.235, 4.565, 7.895};

        List<double[]> lb1=new List<double[]>();
        lb1.Add(items1);
        lb1.Add(items2);
        List<double[]> lb2=new List<double[]>();
        lb2.Add(items3);
        lb2.Add(items4);
        List<double[]> lb3=new List<double[]>();
        lb3.Add(items5);

        MyList.Add(lb1);
        MyList.Add(lb2);
        MyList.Add(lb3);

        List<double[]>List1items = new List<double[]>();
        //MyList[0] is lb1
        List1items = MyList[0]; 
        //Print Second Double array items2's Second Item 4.562 
        Console.WriteLine(List1items[1][1]);

        //Same result as above - get a value
        Console.WriteLine(MyList[0][1][1]);

        double[] RowValues = MyList[0][1]; 
        Console.WriteLine(RowValues[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double doubleValue = MyList[1][2][1]; 
double[] RowValues = MyList[1][2];
```

"Not working" isn't very helpful to us, but are you *sure* it's not working? Both of those are legal code and should do what the question is asking about, assuming you have actually populated the `MyList` variable such that you have at least *two* Lists in there, and the *third* array in the *second* List has an array with at least *two* elements. Remember, indexing starts at **zero**, not at one.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to tell what's not working when you don't provide a sample with data. It seems to me that, since your first idea is correct, then you don't understand that Arrays and Lists are `0` based, or you are not populating your lists/arrays with enough data and are trying to reference an index that doesn't exist (you're accessing the fourth item in the double array of the third list from the second list of lists).

Here is an illustrative example of how you would select a single item, after populating a `List<List<double[]>>` with some data:

```
double[] doubleArray = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<double[]> doubleArrayList = new List<double[]> { doubleArray };
List<List<double[]>> MyList = new List<List<double[]>> { doubleArrayList };

var singleItem = MyList[0][0][0];

Console.WriteLine(singleItem);
```

**Output**

`1`

Comment: I am new in C#, I have just started using it a few day ago , before this I was using language where the first index is 1 not 0, so, I used to write 1 instead of 0 for the first index. I know that, in the most programming languages, the first index is 0. As I mentioned there is not any mistake in the previous code. It is working.

Answer (score -1):

The previous code is working.

[1] To get first list in MyList

```
 List<double[]>List1items = new List<double[]>();
 List1items = MyList[0];
```

[2] one array from the list

```
double[] RowValues = MyList[1][2]; // this will return the array in index 2 of the second list (third item in List 2)
```

[3] one value form the array

```
double doubleValue = MyList[1][2][1];
```